# ASMX Service and Lack of Crossdomain.xml file

Tags: apache-flex

I have an issue with an asmx service I am trying to access. No crossdomain file. I read there is a way around this using HTTPService instead of a webservice. Still cannot load the wsdl. See code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
var dataService:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
dataService.url = 
    "http://flexmappers.com/proxy.php?url=http://www.server.net/carbon.asmx";
dataService.method = "POST";
dataService.addEventListener("result", onCarbonCalcResult);
dataService.addEventListener("fault", onCarbonCalcFault);
//dataService.resultFormat = "xml"

var params:Object = new Object();
params["call"] = "getCarbon";
params.area = carbonarea;
params.geojson = geojson;
dataService.send(params);
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

The crossdomain.xml at http://flexmappers.com/crossdomain.xml looks ok.

Answer (score 1):

> No crossdomain file. I read there is a
>   way around this using HTTPService
>   instead of a webservice

It sounds like you were misinformed.

In browser based applications, neither HTTPService, WebService, and RemoteObject tags are not allowed to access content on a remote server unless a crossdomain.xml file exists allowing such access.  They can all access content on the same domain as the SWF without a crossdomain.xml file in place.

To get around this, you can use an HTTP Proxy on the same server that serves your SWF.  You could also use an AIR app which does not run in a browser, and therefore exists in a different security sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own proxy with BlazeDS or Apache HTTP.